# variable was written but never used in Swift 2.0 & Xcode 7

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7-beta5

When I create a variable without String() to initialize the variable an error shows up alerting, "variable not initialize", same error shows up when I directly assign

`var username: String = usernameTextfieldSigup.text!`

And when I initialize the variable using the code below,

```
var username: String = String()
username = usernameTextfieldSignup.text!
```

warning comes up, variable 'username' was written but never used.

I know I could just ignore these warnings but I'd like a cleaner code.
I'm using Xcode7 beta5 release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the username without a value first:

```
var username: String
```

and then assign a value to it in your initializer:

```
// replace with your (valid) initializer
func init() {
    username = usernameTextfieldSignup.text!
}
```

However, I'm sure that `usernameTextfieldSignup.text` won't have a value until the user ha actually provided a value. So in that case I would recommend to make `username` an optional so you can set it's value when you need to:

```
var username: String?
```

and then when setting it:

```
username = usernameTextfieldSignup.text
```

and when accessing it:

```
if let uname = username {
    // do something with the uname
}
```

Also, the `variable 'username' was written but never used` warning you're seeing is probably because you write to / initialise `username` but there's no code actually reading it, so it's kind of a useless variable according to the compiler then.

Answer (score 0):

To init an empty string you have to either make it explicit or optional like so:

```
let string: String!
let string: String?
```

You can do this with any datatype.

Comment: That doesn't initialise anything, it just tells the compile that it will be initialized / have a value at some point in time.